# "Sweets are not necessary for surviving but bread and water are." is a correct sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure

I have a question about the following sentence:

> "Sweets are not necessary for surviving but bread and water **are**."

I would like to know if I can end this sentence with "are" (without extension of "are necessary for surviving".

Answer (score 2):

#### Yes, it is.

(Notice how I didn't bother to include "a correct sentence" after the word *is.*)

That said, I might restructure that sentence in a more formal context, such as an academic paper: *Unlike bread and water, sweets are not necessary for survival.*